# Need to write a "blendList" function, without using any builtin functions besides 'length'

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Define a function
>
> ```
> blendList : 'a list * 'a list -> 'a list
> ```
>
> that takes two lists and returns one list containing a "blend" of the two lists with values selected in strict alternation from the two lists. Do not use any built-in Standard ML functions other than `length`.
>
> Some examples:
>
> ```
> blendList([1,2], [100,200,300,400]) (* Returns [ 1 ,100,2 ,200,300,400] *)
> blendList([200,100,300,900], [3,1]) (* Returns [ 200 ,3,100 ,1,300,900] *)
> blendList([],[100,200]) (* Returns [100,200] *)
> blendList([1,2],[]) (* Returns [1,2] *)
> ```

How do I do this?

Comment: You don't need `length`, so it's a bit odd to let you use it.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the following code:

```
fun blendList ([], l) = l
  | blendList(l, []) = l
  | blendList(a :: restA, b :: restB) = a :: b :: blendList(restA, restB);
  
blendList([1,2], [100,200,300,400]); (* Returns [ 1 ,100,2 ,200,300,400] *)
blendList([200,100,300,900], [3,1]); (* Returns [ 200 ,3,100 ,1,300,900] *)
blendList([],[100,200]); (* Returns [100,200] *)
blendList([1,2],[]); (* Returns [1,2] *)
blendList([1,2],[1,2]); (* Returns [1,1,2,2] *)
```

We split the blendList into 3 options:

1. The first list is empty.
2. The second list is empty.
3. Both have entries.

In the first option, we take the second list. in the second option, we take the first list. In the last one, we take both of the first elements, and activating the same method again, with what is left.

Note, that if both lists are of the same size, it will get to the last call `blendList[[], []]`, which will fall into the first case, and return `[]`.